# Binding Pushpin Background in XAML ControlTemplate doesn't work

Tags: xaml, binding, windows-phone-8, bing-maps

I have a primary color used throughout my Windows Phone app, but I don't seem to be able to bind it to a Pushpin.Background in XAML. Instead I have to resort to creating the Pushpin in the C# code behind for the UserControl.

Strangely though, I have another totally custom Pushpin ControlTemplate defined that is allowing me to bind to the primary color.

PrimaryColor is of type System.Windows.Media.Color

Any ideas what the issue is?

In the below code I can bind Ellipse.Fill to my PrimaryColor in the UserLocationPushpinControlTemplate, but I cannot bind m:Pushpin.Background in the UserWaypointPushpinControlTemplate.

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyMap"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="480"
    DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <ControlTemplate x:Key="UserLocationPushpinControlTemplate" TargetType="m:Pushpin">
                <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid" Width="34" Height="34">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Grid MinHeight="30" MinWidth="30">
                            <Ellipse Margin="1"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Width="30"
                                Height="30"
                                Stroke="White"
                                StrokeThickness="3">
                                <Ellipse.Fill>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding PrimaryColor, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                </Ellipse.Fill>
                            </Ellipse>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>

            <ControlTemplate x:Key="UserWaypointPushpinControlTemplate" TargetType="m:Pushpin">
                <m:Pushpin Foreground="White">
                    <m:Pushpin.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding PrimaryColor, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </m:Pushpin.Background>
                </m:Pushpin>
            </ControlTemplate>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I never got to the bottom of the issue I refactored some of my code to add a styles XAML file with the following entry:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="PrimaryColorBrush" Color="#FF86A406" />
```

This was a better solution for my scenario, but unfortunately I no longer have my code in a state to test any suggestions anyone may have. Sorry.